# Service and telecom requirements

Tags: java, web-services, testing, rest, telecommunication

I have a question concerning about application testing coupled with external interfaces (REST - Representational State Transfer).

Well, let's say I want to develop a service which would use the platform Telco 2.0 (the telecommunication interfaces) eg. Location API and SMS API.

And now please advise m what parameters / attributes should have this completed service, which are valuable / desirable for the telecommunication operator (think about specificity profile of telecom) ?

I thought, that i should examine the service (although some think it misses the goal, it must be a greater link with the operator and the Telco 2.0 platform which provides the interfaces SMS/Location API) eg. "commutation" and query processing by service, performance, scalability (let us assume that the service has access to a few million mobile subscribers), maybe safety of this service?

What test should i perform :

- What should be the theoretical performance of the Telco 2.0 platform provider (theoretical, because stress tests of Telco 2.0 platform (SMS/Location API) can not be performed) to be able to handle request by REST (Representational State Transfer)?
- Describe the testing functions - delayed service, traffic generated on the SMS / Location API as a function of the number of users who use the application.
- Other?

I would ask for your help ;) If there is literature/bibliography related to this case, the methodology / testing schemes for the application for telecommunication industry just let me know ;)

Additional question - what does it mean to test the service with parameters TUPS and CAPS? (unfortunately I could not find anything about this)

**EDIT**

I don't mean to test transport layer (SS7), but how to develop or use existing concept of testing service in service layer. Obviously I need take into account the specificities of the telecommunications networks and I am not sure if I can use usual testing techniques from IT.

Can anyone advise what to do in this topic?

Lucas

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telephone User Part (**TUP**) and Camel Application Part (**CAP**) are the protocol used in Telecom world, both are present in **SS7 stack**.

Please refer the manual of Telco 2.0 for knowing the performance of the platform, I'm sure the bench-marking is already been done on that.